# Livewire - Passing Data To View & Component from URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I need to pass my data from the url and it works in the console log, but something happened to the view, it does not render the variable and the view loads just the footer, can anyone help me out please?

web routes:

```
Route::view('/aplicacion', 'application.visa-americana');
Route::get('/aplicacion/{id}', VisaUsaComponent::class);
```

layout:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
{{-- livewire interactions --}}
      @livewire('applications.visa-usa-component')
@stop
```

Component:

```
use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class VisaUsaComponent extends Component
{
 
  public $post;

public function mount($id)
  {
    $this->post = User::findOrFail($id);
  }

  public function render()
  {
    return view('livewire.applications.visa-usa-component');
  }
}
```

View:

```
<div>
      {{ $post->name }}
</div>
```

Comment: What you have should work. Can you show a screenshot of what happens?

Comment: By default, Livewire will render the ShowPosts component into the `{{ $slot }}` of a blade layout component located at: `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`. Can you show that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
public function render()
  {
    return view('livewire.applications.visa-usa-component')->layout('your layout address')->section('content');
  }
```

Livewire use `{{$slot}}` for render and `app.blade.php` for layout, if you want change them, you must pass to `render` function

don't forget use `@livewireScripts` and `@livewireStyles` in `app.layout.php`